# How to change GridView Column type from TextBox to LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to know how to allow Gridview column to accept LinkButton. By default, GridView Column is set to accept TextBox controls but I need to have a LinkButton control. My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Globalization;


    namespace GridView_Tutorial
    {
        public partial class GridView : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mehdi-PC\\SqlExpress; Initial Catalog=PIMS; Integrated Security=true");
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM quest_categories", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                //add a blank row to returned DataTable 
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
                //creating the first row of Gridview to be editable
                GridView1.EditIndex = 0;

                //Data Sourcing and binding
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                //Changing the Text for Inserting a New Record
                ((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "Insert";
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Following line of code is throwing error:

```
((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "Insert";
```

Error Message is:

```
InvalidCastException is unhandled by the user.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.
```

When I change the code from:

```
((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "Insert";
```

to

```
((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "Insert";
```

Error goes away, and code inserts a textbox in datatable.

Please help me to insert a LinkButton instead of a TextBox.

Regards

Comment: "code inserts a textbox in datatable" what does that mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("Shipper", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ShipperTemp", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("CShipper1", "1");
    dt.Rows.Add("BShipper2", "2");
    dt.Rows.Add("AShipper1", "1");
    dt.Rows.Add("EShipper1", "2");
    dt.Rows.Add("DShipper4", "4");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    //creating the first row of Gridview to be editable
    GridView1.EditIndex = 0;

    //Data Sourcing and binding
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //Changing the Text for Inserting a New Record
    //((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "Insert";

}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Clear(); // Comment this line if you do not want to hide Textbox from First Cell first Row
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        btn.ID = "ID";
        btn.Text = "Insert";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please explain the following line of code in your own words? 

(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)

Comment: If we do not add this condition then it will add insert LinkButton in every row.

Comment: Ok. Got that. Thanks. 

Can you please help me in updating and rebinding data to sql datbase from DataGrid. 

Right now when I click EDIT button on GridView, record pops up in a new window, and after I finish editing and press "UPDATE" on the new window, it inserts the record in a new row on GridView but that record is not "DESELECTED" and is "EDITABLE". I want it to be deselected and not-editable in GridView. 

I am kind of lost. What information do I need to paste you here so you get an idea of my coding? 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have inserted a GridView on webform,linked to sql database.for editing purposes,when user clicks on a button btnEditRecord (given on the main view <vStart>),btnEditRecord_Click event takes users to a new view called <vGrid>.On <vGrid> I have GridView1 with all the records populated from SQL database. Each record is pasted in GridView1 with 3 Linkbuttons (Edit,Delete,Select).When users clicks Edit,new view <vRecords> pops up,with all the record fields given in Gridview.User edits information and clicks a button called btnUPDATE given on <vRecords>.It updates_ (to be continued)

Comment: _ the record but on Gridview1, it doesnt show the edited record as bound-to-Gridview like other records. Rather it shows it as selected and editable. I need it to be shown as updated and bounded.Hope you understand my problem now. Please help. Thanks